# Creating dynamic models in Appconfig.ready

Tags: python, django, model

I am working on a Django project for which I need to create dynamic models that are based on explicit/static models (i.e. classes in models.py). Right now I am using the `class_prepared` signal, but the models are not fully processed by Django yet at that time, which leads to reduced functionality.

Is it possible to create dynamic models in the Appconfig.ready function? Code in the ready function will only be run after everything is properly initialized. If you create a dynamic model in that function, will it still be processed properly by Django or not?

I've tried creating a model in the ready function, and it seems to work. I can access the _meta object and functions like _meta.get_fields() without errors. (Which is not possible before the ready function)

I'm just scared that some internal Django stuff might work different because the model was created after Django is supposed to be done iniatializing.